# How do I fill these fields in using Scrivener? Is there some document properties to fill out?

Tags: scrivener

[image]

How do I fill in these notatable fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These fields are filled in from the project's metadata. In both Scrivener 2 and 3, you access the metadata through the Compile dialogue.

- In Scrivener 2, metadata is a menu option in the left-hand pane. Click it, and the editable fields appear in the right pane.
- In Scrivener 3, metadata is a mini-tab above the right pane. By default the right pane shows your document outline. Click on the second symbol, the one that looks like a tag or flag, and the metadata text fields will appear.

The contents of these are saved as soon as you change them. You can edit your project's metadata, then choose <kbd>Cancel</kbd> to close the Compile dialogue. It will remember the metadata (and any other compile settings changes) for future compiles.

Note that your compile settings depend on what compile format you have chosen. If you change output formats, always review all your settings to make sure everything is as it should be.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very good answer!